# How do I rewrite a series of conditional statements with Q promises in node.js?

Tags: node.js, promise, q

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
  var company_id = req.company_id;
  var client = new Client(req.body);

  Company.findOne({_id: company_id}, function(err, company) {
    if(err) {
      response = {
        status: 'error',
        error: err
      }

      return res.json(response);
    } else if(!company) {
      response = {
        status: 'error',
        error: 'Invalid company_id'
      }

      return res.json(response);
    } else {
      client.save(function(err) {
        if(err) {
          response = {
            status: 'error',
            error: err
          }
        } else {
          response = {
            status: 'ok',
            client: client
          }
        }

        return res.json(response);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

That's my code (using `Express`, if it matters). I'm trying to learn more about promises, specifically with `Q`. I feel that this is the perfect kind of logic that can be implemented with promises to avoid this hairy conditional nest. But I'm not sure how to start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I'm not sure how to start?

Start by removing the callbacks and using the Promise methods instead. Then put the error handling in a dedicated error callback, instead of using that condition. Also, you can put the code for building that `response` object in the very end (removing the duplication), and only pass/throw the `err` down to it.

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
  var client = new Client(req.body);

  Q.ninvoke(Company, "findOne", {_id: req.company_id}).then(function(company) {
    if(!company)
      throw 'Invalid company_id';
    else
      return company;
  }).then(function(company) {
    return Q.ninvoke(client, "save");
  }).then(function(saveResult) {
    return {
      status: 'ok',
      client: client
    };
  }, function(err) {
    return {
      status: 'error',
      error: err
    };
  }).done(function(response) {
    res.json(response);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not really the use case for Promises. Promises are a method for eliminating deeply nested callbacks in node.js, not complex logic dealing with a result, like you have in your code. Think of the case where the outcome of your `.findOne` query would determine the next query you need to make - this quickly leads to a nested callback situation, which can be made less nested and more natural to read, evaluate, re-factor, and build upon if you use Promises.

You do have one nested callback for the outcome of your `.save` call. So, you might successfully re-factor this using Promises, like so

```
new Promise(function() {
    Company.findOne()
    ...
.then(function(company) {
    company.update()
    ...
}, function(err) {
    ...
})
```

The starting point is to wrap your first query so that it returns a promise instead of dealing with callbacks within callbacks.

Comment: Clearing deep  nested callbacks is not the use case for promises at all, you can even use async library or simply naming functions to avoid nesting.

Comment: Indeed there are other methods and libraries that can help with the problem that I believe the original question was asking about. But, making it simpler to compose a sequence of serial (or parallel) operations is one of the stated motivations for promises.