# Multiple promises in Node with error handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise

How can I avoid nesting-hell with a chain of service calls in Node.js, where I'd like to throw a given error and exit the entire chain in certain instances? Here's an example of the chain:

1. Load Mongoose object.
2. If load fails, `res.send(404)`; if load succeeds, go to the next `then()`.
3. Call 3rd party API to get some data.
4. If API call fails, send proper response (say the proper status code is `500` just for the sake of this problem)
5. If API call succeeds, render the page.

   ```
   SomeMongooseModel.findOne({id:123}).exec()
   .then(function(response)
   {
       // If group is empty, would like to res.send(404) and resolve the 
       // promise immediately.
   })
   .then(function(response)
   {
       // Hit 3rd party API to retrieve data. If there's an issue, return
       // response code of 500 and resolve promise immediately.

       // Assuming the API call was a success, build out an object and render
       // the page like so:
       res.render('some.template', {data: some_data});
   });
   ```

I think this is a decent example of what I'm trying to achieve, but what if we had even more async calls to handle? How can we exit the chain immediately? I've done a bit of searching and I know that I have a lot more to learn, but I'm not finding the ability to simply exit the chains immediately.

Comment: I should add that I've tried using `.catch()...` but receive the error that `Object #<Promise> has no method 'catch'` - it seems this is sugar that only some objects provide and isn't a requisite of the promise spec?

Comment: calling the reject() method that the promise provides should cancel subsequent chained calls.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [How do I rewrite a series of conditional statements with Q promises in node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21910577/1048572)

Comment: @dandavis: A promise object should not have a `.reject` method. Or is this some obscure self-made promise library?

Comment: @Bergi: reject is the 2nd argument to the Promise constructor, how it's provided to instances is implementation-specific.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now, you want to construct a rejected promise. Actually, `throw`ing in a `then` handler should be enough

Comment: i guess i should have said, check the source of the exec() method to see if it provides a way to reject(), and if not, you can always re-roll a new sequence manually. (something like http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-promisifying-xmlhttprequest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When faced with this I normally separate everything into functions, which I then pass a reference into the promise. With good names it also benefits the reading:

```
function resolveNotFoundIfGroupEmptyOrForwardResponse( response ) { res.send(404) }
function hit3rdPartyApiBasedOnResponse( response ) { 
// throw exception if there is an issue. next step will run the failure state
}    
function render500() { ... }
function renderTemplateWithData( some_data ) { 
   res.render('some.template', {data: some_data});
}

SomeMongooseModel.findOne({id:123}).exec()
    .then( resolveNotFoundIfGroupEmptyOrForwardResponse )
    .then( hit3rdPartyApiBasedOnResponse )
    .then( renderTemplateWithData, render500 )
    .done();
```

If the function requires an input param that is not comming from the promise chain, then I normally do a function that returns a function.

```
function doStuffWithParamsCommingFromTwoSides( main_input ) {
   return function( promise_input ) {
         ...
   }
}

then( doStuffWithParamsCommingFromTwoSides( "foobar" ) )
```

---

Following Promises/A+ specification, the `then` steps look like this:

```
promise.then(onFulfilled, onRejected, onProgress)
```

Whenever an exception is thrown the next step will run the `onRejected`. Eventually bubbling up to the `done` which can also be used to catch the exception bubble.

```
promise.done(onFulfilled, onRejected, onProgress)
```

Comment: This is so helpful! Thanks for sharing. I'm not used to the idea of having a bunch of functions in a route like that, but I suppose for calls like this it's the saner approach.