# Confused about JQuery promises

Tags: jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

I'm really trying hard to understand the behavior or JQuery's promise().

I want to do 3 (unrelated, but back-to-back) AJAX queries :

```
1. GET the user data
2. POST an image
3. POST another image
```

Then, I'm doing a load of things that are based on then results of said queries.

Now, the $.when(ajax, ajax, ajax).then(userData, img1, img2) functions work great for this as of now, **but** what if I want my ajax calls to be wrapped around conditions, as so :

```
$.when(
 if(...){
   $.ajax({ ...GET user data... });
 }
 if(...){
   $.ajax({ ...POST image... });
 }
 if(...){
   $.ajax({ ...POST image... });
 }
).then(function(userData, img1, img2){
 if(img1){
  ...do something with img1...
 }
 ...same for other responses...
});
```

I'm aware that my code doesn't contain any promise, but really, everything I've tried failed pretty badly in this scenario.

Any hint/tip appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How about wrapping the ajax functions in other functions where you can use your conditions e.g: `$.when(function ajaxForSomeCondition(){if (someCondition){return $.ajax...}})`

Comment: also see [if with asynchronous case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29802688/1048572), [rewrite a series of conditional statements](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21913675/1048572) or [promises and if/else statement](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21911369/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the ternary operator, and a way to build default value promises:

```
$.when(
  … ? $.ajax({/* GET user data */}) : $.when(null),
  … ? $.ajax({/* POST first image */}) : $.when(null),
  … ? $.ajax({/* POST second image */}) : $.when(null)
).then(function(userData, img1, img2){
  if (userData)
    … // do something with userData
  if (img1)
    … // do something with img1
  …
});
```

This will, based on the respective condition, either send an ajax request and get a promise for its result, or construct an already-fulfilled promise for the value `null`. Then all of the three promises are awaited.

Comment: (related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599798/if-else-flow-in-promise-bluebird)

Answer (score 3):

You can pass non-promises to jQuery's `$.when` it'll deal them just fine:

```
$.when(15, undefined, $.ajax(...)).then(function(fifteen, undef, result){
    // this will run when the result is ready
});
```

If you want to do something *based on the result* of the calls you can chain them via `.then`, if you want to run them one after the other, you can use thenable chaining instead of `$.when` which works concurrently.